# django __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'param'

Tags: python, django

My **View.py**

```
class AccountCreate(RequestPassingFormViewMixin, MyCreateView):
    template_name = 'dashboard/account_form.html'
    form_class = AccountForm
    model = Account

def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs = super(AccountCreate, self).get_form_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
    common = get_object_or_404(Common, pk=self.kwargs['common_pk'])
    combination_price = Account(common=common)
    kwargs['instance'] = combination_price
    return kwargs

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('dashboard_account_list', kwargs={'chain_pk': self.object.chain.id})

def form_valid(self, form):
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    discount = form.cleaned_data['discount']
    account_list = form.cleaned_data['account_list']
    self.object.common = get_object_or_404(Common, pk=self.kwargs['common_pk'])
    code = Account.get_code(self.object.common, account_list, discount)
    self.object.code = code
    self.object.save()
    form.save_m2m()
    return redirect(self.get_success_url())
```

and this is my form.py file

```
class AccountForm(autocomplete_light.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Account

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.request = kwargs.pop("request")        
    super(AccountForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    common = Common.objects.get(pk=self.request.session.get('common_pk'))
    products = Account.objects.filter(chain=chain)
    form.fields['discount'].queryset = Discount.objects.filter(product__in=products)
    form.fields['account_list'].queryset = AccountList.objects.filter(common=common)

def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(AccountForm, self).clean()
    discount = cleaned_data['discount']
    if len(discount) <= 1:
        self._errors["discount"] = self.error_class(['Choose at least two discount'])
        return cleaned_data
    account_list = cleaned_data['account_list']
    common = Common.objects.get(pk=self.request.session.get('common_pk'))
    code =Account.get_code(common, account_list, discount)
    if not self.instance or (self.instance.code != code or self.instance.account_list != account_list):
        if Account.objects.filter(code=code, account_list=account_list).exists():
            msg1 = 'Already exists'
            self._errors["discount"] = self.error_class([msg1])
    return cleaned_data
```

I am tryng to add auto suggest option in my m2m field.I have added autocomplete in my form.py file.

But the problem is that,after adding **autocomplete** in the form,i am facing the error.

Comment: check declaration of `autocomplete_light.ModelForm.__init__` and simply `pop` unwanted ones before call it (like you did with request) ...

Comment: *Where* does the error occur? You've included a lot of code here and most of it doesn't seem relevant to the error, where is the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

i have found the solution,in my forms,the `__init__` method don't have the 'param' keyword argument,so i have rewrite my form.py something like this,adding `self.param = kwargs.pop("param")` and its worked.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.request = kwargs.pop("request")
    self.param = kwargs.pop("param")
    super(CombinationPriceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    chain = Chain.objects.get(pk=self.request.session.get('chain_pk'))
    products = Product.objects.filter(chain=chain)
    self.fields['variants'].queryset = Variant.objects.filter(product__in=products)
    self.fields['price_list'].queryset = PriceList.objects.filter(chain=chain)
```